# Dreamweaver Installation Issues

Tags: dreamweaver

I have installed Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 but it is not opening and displaying the error as follow:

This application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

I have Windows Vista installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Do one or more of the following solutions:

**Solution 1: Install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 runtime. (Visual C++ users only)**

If you are a Microsoft Visual C++ user, then do the following steps:

1. Install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 runtime.
2. Reboot the machine
3. Relaunch the Suite applications.

**Solution 2: Reboot your system and restart the applications.**
If you have just installed Creative Suite, then perform the following steps:

1. Reboot the machine.
2. Relaunch the Suite applications

[Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/error-side-side-configuration-incorrect.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply dude, but It's still displaying the same error.

Comment: The same error "This application has failed to start because its side-by-side config is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail"

Comment: I did all the steps that you refered

Comment: You can try this, too: http://www.vistax64.com/software/245768-side-side-configuration-incorrect.html I see that many people had this problem. :)

Comment: @SyedHaider You are welcome. Don't forget to mark and vote up the answer. Thank you.